# radio button checked by default issue

Tags: angular, typescript

in my reactive forms, i use forms value for radio buttons to be checked by default.
also i change content onclick, when you click on first currency, numbers are different but default number isn't checked. i want 25000 to be checked when you click on first symbol. how can i achieve that?
here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-r8hn18?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

i tried changing value on click but it doesn't work, like this:

```
  lari() {
    this.currencySymbol = "₾";
    let amount = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(1)
      .get("amount").value;
    amount = "25000";
    this.currencySymbol = "₾";
    this.amountArray = [
      {
        value: 25000
      },
      {
        value: 50000
      },
      {
        value: 75000
      },
      {
        value: 100000
      }
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use setValue to set the default value:

```
(this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(1)
      .get("amount").setValue("25000");
```

I have edited the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-fc7dh6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) here. Please verify..